# Http source configuration doesn't work for flume

Tags: apache-kafka, flume, flume-ng

Iam a beginner to Apache flume. Iam trying to pull data from a REST API and take it through flume and send to a kafka topic. But it is not working so far. The configuration I tried to use is shown below.There is a test GET API at localhost:8080/kafka/publish/ in the system. Iam trying to get data from this. The below configuration I tried pulling from flume documentation.

```
a1.sources = r1
a1.channels = c1
a1.sources.r1.type = http
a1.sources.r1.port = 8080
a1.sources.r1.channels = c1
a1.sources.r1.handler = org.apache.flume.source.http.JSONHandler
a1.sources.r1.handler.nickname = random props
a1.sources.r1.HttpConfiguration.sendServerVersion = false
a1.sources.r1.ServerConnector.idleTimeout = 300

a1.sinks.k1.channel = c1
a1.sinks.k1.type = org.apache.flume.sink.kafka.KafkaSink
a1.sinks.k1.kafka.topic = simple
a1.sinks.k1.kafka.bootstrap.servers = localhost:9092
a1.sinks.k1.kafka.flumeBatchSize = 20
a1.sinks.k1.kafka.producer.acks = 1
a1.sinks.k1.kafka.producer.linger.ms = 1
a1.sinks.k1.kafka.producer.compression.type = snappy
```

Can anyone help me solve this. What is the problem here?

The logs is added below

```
2020-12-03 11:16:17,696 (conf-file-poller-0) [WARN - org.apache.flume.conf.FlumeConfiguration$AgentConfiguration.validateConfigFilterSet(FlumeConfiguration.java:623)] Agent configuration for 'a1' has no configfilters.
2020-12-03 11:16:17,713 (conf-file-poller-0) [WARN - org.apache.flume.conf.FlumeConfiguration$AgentConfiguration.isValid(FlumeConfiguration.java:373)] Agent configuration for 'a1' does not contain any valid channels. Marking it as invalid.
2020-12-03 11:16:17,714 (conf-file-poller-0) [WARN - org.apache.flume.conf.FlumeConfiguration.validateConfiguration(FlumeConfiguration.java:154)] Agent configuration invalid for agent 'a1'. It will be removed.
2020-12-03 11:16:17,715 (conf-file-poller-0) [INFO - org.apache.flume.conf.FlumeConfiguration.validateConfiguration(FlumeConfiguration.java:163)] Post-validation flume configuration contains configuration for agents: []
2020-12-03 11:16:17,718 (conf-file-poller-0) [WARN - org.apache.flume.node.AbstractConfigurationProvider.getConfiguration(AbstractConfigurationProvider.java:139)] No configuration found for this host:a1
2020-12-03 11:16:17,730 (conf-file-poller-0) [INFO - org.apache.flume.node.Application.startAllComponents(Application.java:162)] Starting new configuration:{ sourceRunners:{} sinkRunners:{} channels:{} }
```

Comment: Is your API returning the correct format of events? https://github.com/jrnz/flume/blob/master/flume-ng-core/src/main/java/org/apache/flume/source/http/JSONHandler.java#L45

Comment: @OneCricketeer It is returning a JSON response. I have added the logs data for some extra clarity may give on the issue.

Comment: Sure, but that json must be in a very specific format, if you see the linked code

Comment: But yes, you need to actually setup channel c1

Comment: @OneCricketeer How do I setup channel c1

Comment: Well, in your most recent question, you seem to now have a memory channel, but there are also Kafka channels, if you are reading the documentation

Comment: If I may ask, though, why use Flume at all? The django service could just write to Kafka itself. More specifically, Flume has had very little active development over the past few years, so you could either argue its stable or try to find another solution that's a bit more flexible to your goals

Comment: @OneCricketeer The major reason is I want to pull data from multiple APIs and if I could perfect a configuration which lets me pull data from multiple APIs then I would only need to change the URL to pull data. And I have been testing through some others such as Kafka connect and Nifi. Need to see how good this is.

Comment: I would think Nifi would suffice, and would scale better if installed in a clustered environment, given a flowfile of addresses, passed through a gethttp processor

Comment: @OneCricketeer Can the HTTP source be configured to pull from a specific Http source such as an GET API endpoint and make flume periodically call the API with dynamic parameters or make flume implement pagination.

Comment: Never used it, actually. I would assume there's a timer on the source, otherwise you'd have to run the agent in a Cron schedule... Doubtful about the paging. Query parameters would simply be added to the url path, if that's configurable